# Error al mover dos JFrame mediante componentMoved (java)

Tags: java, jframe, component

Tengo un programa que, entre otros elementos, usa dos `JFrame`. El primero de ellos es, digamos, el `JFrame` "principal", el cual contiene una serie de `JButtons`, `JLabels`, `JComboBoxs`, etc. y en él está desactivado el método `setUndecorated`. El segundo `JFrame` solamente contiene un `JTable` y un `JScrollPane`, y tiene el método `setUndecorated` activado. Mi idea es que al mover el `JFrame` "principal" se mueva también el `JFrame` que contiene el `JTable`. Para intentar implementar esta función estoy utilizando dos clases .java (he omitido algunas partes del código que no interfieren en el problema que tengo para darle mayor claridad):

Clase panel (esta es la del `JFrame` "principal"):

```
public class Panel extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ComponentListener{

    private JPanel panel = null;

    public Panel(){
        
        panel = new JPanel(){
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                super.paintComponent(g);
                crearImagenes(g); //Este es un método que tengo para actualizar imágenes (me funciona bien)
            }
        };
                       
        panel.setLayout(null);
        this.add(panel);
        panel.addComponentListener(this);

    }
    
    @Override
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
        Point p = panel.getLocation();
        JFrameTablaPersonalizada.getTablaMisRetos().setLocation(p);
        System.out.println(p);
    }

    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
        
    }
}
```

Clase JFrameTablaPersonalizada (esta es la del `JFrame` que contiene el `JTable`):

```
public class JFrameTablaPersonalizada extends JFrame{
    private static JTable tablaMisRetos = null;
    
    public JFrameTablaPersonalizada(){
        setBounds(498, 145, 380, 120);
        TableModel miModelo = new ModeloTablaPersonalizada();
        tablaMisRetos = new JTable(miModelo);
        
        add(new JScrollPane(tablaMisRetos));
        
        tablaMisRetos.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(125);
        tablaMisRetos.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(165);
        tablaMisRetos.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        tablaMisRetos.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false);
        tablaMisRetos.setEnabled(false);

    }
    
    public static JTable getTablaMisRetos() {
        return tablaMisRetos;
    }

    public static void setTablaMisRetos(JTable aTablaMisRetos) {
        tablaMisRetos = aTablaMisRetos;
    }
}

class ModeloTablaPersonalizada extends AbstractTableModel{
    
    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 4;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        /*...*/
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        /*...*/
        return "";

    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int c){
        /*...*/
        return "";
        
    }
    
}
```

Como se puede ver en los códigos, estoy usando `java.awt.event.ComponentListener` en mi clase Panel y desarrollo el método `componentMoved` para que se mueva mi tabla. Aunque desde este último método llamo a la tabla de la otra clase, no consigo que se mueva hacia el mismo punto cada vez que muevo el `JFrame de la clase Panel`. Esto es lo que se me muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al mover el `JFrame` principal, no se mueve a su vez el `JFrame` que contiene el `JTable` como debería:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Por que usaste JFrame como contenedor de la tabla en lugar de JPanel?

Comment: @Sal Porque no me deja añadir un ```JScrollPane``` si es con ```JPanel```. Lo he intentado de muchas formas diferentes mirando preguntas de StackOverflow y no me ha funcionado